# Restore big database from local to the Azure

Tags: sql, database, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I've tried to restore my local database to the Azure SQL database using the SQL Database Migration Wizard http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ but was not able to finish it. My database is about 40GB. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

For such loads I would use the following scenario:

1. Make a database backup from the local server (.bak)
2. Upload this backup to a blob storage using storage explorer of your choice ([Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) or [Cerebrata Azure Explorer](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-explorer/introduction), or anything else).
3. Create a Virtual Machine from Gallery using image with SQL Server.
4. RDP to that VM, download the BAK, restore it to local SQL Server
5. Use the SQLAzure MW to migrate data to Azure SQL Database from the Azure VM.
6. Delete the VM, or as minimum, shut it down **through the portal** to avoid charging.

Use the same Data Center for both Azure SQL DB and Azure VM.